# Add image to product programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a script to import a list of product from xls. It works fine except for the image; I use the following bits of code:

```
...

if(file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS . $gallery_img)){
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS . $gallery_img, null, false, false);
}

...
```

The image is actually added to the product but it's not selected, so it does not show in the frontend:

[image]

How can I "select" it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check Magento's `addImageToMediaGallery` function located at **app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product.php** file,

```
public function addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaAttribute=null, $move=false, $exclude=true)
```

You will see that second attribute is code of attribute with type 'media_image'. This attribute will define which image will be set as which media image.
By default there are three.

1. image
2. small_image
3. thumbnail

So you need to pass value to your second argument as below

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS . $gallery_img, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```

to set them as main image, small image and thumbnail image.

Answer (score 4):

Look at Mage_Catalog_Model_Product to become familiar with addImageToMediaGallery() and other methods you'll undoubtedly need to be aware of in the future.

```
// Add three image sizes to media gallery
$mediaArray = array(
    'thumbnail'   => $putPathHere,
    'small_image' => $putPathHere,
    'image'       => $putPathHere,
);

// Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';

foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName) {
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
    if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
        try {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
    }
}
```

### **Or**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'bulkimages/101/';

$productsData = array('Purple-Crown-Ring-MFAS.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MFC.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MSAS.jpg','Purple-Crown-Ring-MSF.jpg');

$productSKU = '111';
$ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);

foreach($productsData as $fileName){
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        $ourProduct->save();
        echo "done ";
    } else {
        echo $productSKU . " not done";
        echo "<br>";
    }   
}
?>
```